# Play framework 2.0.4 file download

Tags: java, playframework, download

I'm having trouble sending a file to the browser from play to initiate a download. At the moment this is what I am doing:

```
File sitemap = new File(output);

response().setHeader("Cache-Control", "public");
response().setHeader("Content-Description", "File Transfer");
response().setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=download.xml");
response().setHeader("Content-Type",  "mime/type");
response().setHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "binary");

return ok(new FileInputStream(sitemap)).as("application/xml");
```

All this does is print the contents of the file to the console. I have tried this and get the same result:

```
return ok(sitemap);
```

Anyone have any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: I have no problem when using your code. Do you have a reverse-proxy like nginx? If yes, the file must be converted to a byte-array to pass the proxy.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar problem in the past, and the reason was that the URL (in the conf/routes file) that was pointing to this function ended with a "/". Changing the URL itself to end with .xml in the routes file helped, like this:

```
GET     /file/download/download.xml controllers.Admin.getDownloadFile()
```